# How to reconstruct an old image?

Tags: image, extrapolation

I have taken a picture of a very old image . That picture is itself a bit scarred and so the content of the image is not properly visible. Is there any image re construction or extrapolation software available which I can download and use it to re construct the image and make it very clear to the naked eye ?

Comment: `photoshop`, `the gimo` ...

Comment: @Jasen : Is there no online tool available, where in I will just upload my image and it will render the pixels which are not visible ?

Comment: How about posting the image? Or try Googling "photo retouching".

Comment: @TheDarkKnight that's not the original question, I am not google.

Comment: @Jasen : The original question is about any available software, online or otherwise. Thanks for the previous answer, however if you don't know something when that thing is being requested of you, just say that you are not aware of it. Since I am a sentient human being I know that you are not google.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using photoshop but if you want to use other tools that are maybe easier (more friendly) than akvis.
I honestly would go the route of photoshop and go through photo restoring tutorials (tons online).
Good luck